# Intellij Idea scanner.nextLine() returns empty String

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've noticed a weird behavior in Intellij Idea Community Edition run window.

Here is my code

```java
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        var list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        String[] arr = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        for (String number : arr) {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(number));
        }

        // scanner.nextLine();

        int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
```

When I run it with input

```
1 2 4 5
3
```

It will return empty String `""` on `int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());`, unless I uncomment `scanner.nextLine()` on line 9. Then it works as intended and returns `3`.

I have tried to run compiled code in a Terminal window and it works just fine without extra `scanner.nextLine()`.

I am running it on Zorin OS 16.1, IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Community Edition) from flathub.

This behavior does not occur when I try it on my Windows 11 machine.

My question is why does it occur and how to have the same behavior on all machines?

Comment: This is a known bug in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1, see for example the bug report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293951/Console-readLine-skips-input-in-202211

Comment: You are correct! Installed version 2022.1.2 from snap store and it works as it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Thomas Kläger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5646962/thomas-kl%c3%a4ger) pointed out this is a known bug in Intellij Idea 2022.1.1 . Updating to version 2022.1.2 solved the problem.